# Change Color of Line between Tab and JTable

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, jtabbedpane

I am customizing the visual appearance of my `JTabbedPane`, which contains three `JTables`.

While I was successfully coloring the selection color of the tab, including a changing of the text color, I changed the tab border colors by creating an own `BasicTabbedPaneUI`. But there is still one line, which remained in the way it was. This line is located between the tab and the table. See the following picture:

[image]

The line I am talking about is marked with three litte red dots.
What is this line? If it is a border, where does it belong to? I didn't find a way to set its color. I checked the `JTable`, he `JTabbedPane`, and even the components of the `JTabbedPane`.

Just to show, what I am able to access, I painted every component green.
[image]

You can see, that this blue line still remains.
Does anyone know how to change its color?
Removing it would be another acceptable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `TabbedPane.contentAreaColor`(top of the `TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets`):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public final class BasicTabbedPaneColorTest {
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    //UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets",  new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    //UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets",  new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));

    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", Color.GREEN);
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.highlight",        Color.RED);

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI());
    //tabs.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    //tabs.setOpaque(true);

    tabs.addTab("JTable", new JScrollPane(new JTable(20, 3)));
    tabs.addTab("JTree",  new JScrollPane(new JTree()));
    return tabs;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new BasicTabbedPaneColorTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! It worked with setting `UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", Color.GREEN);`